# Дергается блок при зависимых скролах

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка

Мне необходимо реализовать сложное меню из зависимыми скролами. Первый пункт имеет скрол. Некоторые подпункты имеют также скролы (в зависимости от подпунктов). Третий уровень, карточка, всегда имеет одинаковые размеры.. Я это реализовал, Но возникла проблема - при прокрутке 2 уровня сильно дергается карточка... находил в интернете реализацию с фиксацией карточки, но не знаю как определить момент начала и конца скрола... насколько я понял, то событие скрол возникает с определенной задержкой, поэтому и возникают эти дёргания... В общем виде проблему упрощено показал ниже (нажмите выполнить, в разных браузерах это дёргание видно по разному, в одних больше, в другие меньше)

```js
      $('.scroll-1-wrapper').scroll(function(){
        var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
            top_second = $('.scroll-2-wrapper').scrollTop();

        $(".scroll-2-wrapper").css("top", top);
        $(".scroll-2-wrapper").css("bottom", top * -1);

        $(".scroll-3-wrapper").css("top", top_second);
        $(".scroll-3-wrapper").css("bottom", top_second * -1);
      });

      $(".scroll-2-wrapper").scroll(function(){
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();

        $(this).find(".scroll-3-wrapper").css("top", top);
        $(this).find(".scroll-3-wrapper").css("bottom", top * -1);
      });
```

```css
.scroll-1-wrapper, .scroll-2-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-1-wrapper{
  width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.scroll-2-wrapper{
  width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.scroll-3-wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scroll-1-wrapper, .scroll-2-wrapper, .scroll-3-wrapper, .scroll-3-element {
  height: 400px;
}

.scroll-1-element, .scroll-2-element {
  height: 1000px;
}
.scroll-1-element, .scroll-2-element, .scroll-3-element {
  width: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fe2512, #fef750, #080cf1);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.scroll-2-wrapper, .scroll-3-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-1-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-1-element">
    <div class="scroll-2-wrapper">
      <div class="scroll-2-element">
        <div class="scroll-3-wrapper">
          <div class="scroll-3-element">scroll-3-element</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А usability этого _сложное меню из зависимыми скролами_ точно высокое? Нет возможности реализовать тот же функционал более удобно и не спотыкаясь о _накладные баги_?

Comment: я уже по максимуму сократил это меню и ту информацию, которая там отображается... меню дизайнерское, поэтому я к нему и привязываюсь...